# Relatively Prime numbers VB

Tags: vb.net, primes

I have this number x and i wanted to find all numbers which are relatively prime to it.

my code so far:

```
 For i = 1 To x-1
        if [number n is relatively prime to x] Then
             ListBox1.Items.Add(x)
        End If
  Next
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you mean all numbers *less than* `x` that are coprime with `x` then you need to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two numbers are relatively prime if their greatest common divisor is 1. VB doesn't have the GCD function built-in, but the algorithm is simple enough (and about 2300 years old!):

```
function gcd(m, n)
    while n > 0
        m, n = n, m%n
    return m
```

Note that m and n are assigned simultaneously. I'll leave it to you to complete the VB implementation. You might be interested in googling for the totient of a number and the list of its totatives, which is what you are calculating.

Comment: Yes, see [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) on Wikipedia.

Comment: i am assuming % means modulus?

Comment: Yes, % is the modulus operator.

Comment: just to make sure, does the comma mean multiply?

Comment: No. The line m, n = n, m%n is multiple assignment, so both assignments happen simultaneously. If your language doesn't provide multiple assignment, you could implement it as t=n, n=m%n, m=t.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want only numbers that are smaller than `x`, which are coprime with it - you could also take a generative approach, running a special kind of a sieve. When the multiples of each prime are generated, you'd see if *that sequence* "hits" your upper limit `x` or misses it, and mark all the numbers in it as non-coprimes if it does hit `x`.

Or in "pseudocode" (with Haskell syntax :) ),

```
coprimes n = go( [1..n-1], [2..n-1]) where
  go( xs, []   ) = xs           -- ' no more numbers to sieve - return xs
  go( xs, p:ks ) =              -- ' p is first in candidates, ks is the rest
    let ms = [p, 2*p .. n-1]    -- ' p's multiples
    in
      go( if ( (mod n p) == 0 ) -- ' is n a multiple of p ?
            then (xs\\ms)       -- ' yes: remove p's multiples
            else xs,            -- ' no:  possible coprimes
          ks\\ms )              -- ' candidates to sieve
```

Haskell's set difference `\\` is very inefficient with unordered list representation of sets, but you would naturally encode this efficiently, on top of mutable arrays, in VB.